# Нумерация массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив [1,2,3,4] у них индексы начинаются с 0 до 3,  после выполнения `unset 0 и 1`, индексы у того массива начинаются с 2 до 3. Как сделать так, чтобы после этой функции, они начинались с 0?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону функции `array_splice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr=array('2'=>3,'3'=>4);

foreach($arr as $key =>$value){
$arr1[]=$value;
}
print_r($arr1);
```

Answer (score 9):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `array_values()`

Answer (score -2):

Никак не делать. В 99% случаев массив с индексами 2 и 3 ничуть не хуже массива с индексами 0 и 1

Comment: зависит от задачи, массив с 0 сериализуется в json массив, а с 2-3 в  объект. так что вопрос имеет право на существование.

Comment: @teran это верно